# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not str but my str-object is bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, typeerror, decoding

I am receiving the

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not str
```

but my str-object is bytes and have searched for an answer.

---

This is where the decoding happens without error:

```
for line in tmpFile:
    sl = codecs.decode(bytes(line, encoding = 'utf-8'), encoding  = 'utf-8').strip().split('\t')
    writer.writerow(sl)
```

If I take out the (bytes(line,encofing = 'utf-8') part then I get the TypeError.
This is how I'm opening the file:

```
with open(output_path, mode = 'w') as out_file:
        write_final_output(out_file, delimiter, tmpFile)
```

I've tried opening it with mode = 'w+' and with codecs and I still have the same problem which is that my csv file comes out encoded with the beginning reading like this:

```
b'101361\x01
```

Comment: IS this about getting the output to write as a string? If so, the answer may be as simple as writer.writerow(str(sl))

Comment: I'm trying to properly decode the file and yes output it as a string.